# Programmatically Draw With Measurement Widget

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm using an ArcGIS scene with an AreaMeasurement3D widget to allow users to draw a region to provides some parameters for a db query. I would also like them to be able to type in coordinates and have the widget produce a measurement for them. I see there's a newMeasurement method available but it doesn't seem to support this. Is there some other way to programmatically draw a region with this widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me whether you want to reuse the [AreaMeasurement3D](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-AreaMeasurement3D.html) widget to retrieve the actual measurements or use it to visualize the area. At this point the measurement tools do not support this.

I would suggest to use [`geometryEngine.geodesicArea()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-geometryEngine.html#geodesicArea) or [`geometryEngine.planarArea()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-geometryEngine.html#planarArea) to calculate a measurement from given coordinates.

Using a [GraphicsLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GraphicsLayer.html) you could then visualize the area as shown in the [Add Graphics](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/graphics-basic-3d/index.html) sample.

Comment: I switched to using the sketch tool and similar code to the add graphics example that you linked, but I'm having some difficulties because both of those options fail when trying to draw shapes that cross the 180th meridian. The measurement tool is able to do this. Any idea why?

Comment: Thanks for asking, indeed there is a bug in the API drawing across the 180th meridian. We've detected it recently and will be fixed for the upcoming December release of the JavaScript API.

Comment: I should mention, a preview of the upcoming API where this is fixed is available here: https://github.com/Esri/feedback-js-api-next - please let us know if you have any feedback.